# how can I add an subfolder in the url background in the Sass files in production?

Tags: webpack, next.js

In development mode with **NextJS** i have the paths as in the following example in my **SASS** files:

```
background-image: url(/images/bg-header.png) !important;
```

But in production mode I'm going to upload the website to a subfolder of the domain, example:

```
www.domain.com/subfolder/
```

I need it to build like this:

```
background-image: url(/subfolder/images/bg-header.png) !important;
```

How can I get it?

Also I am using `withCSS` and `withSass` in my configuration file, I tried several `next.config.js`, but nothing worked.

```
const config = {
....
webpack: (config, options) => {
        // config.resolve.alias["@assets"] = '/subfolder/';
        config.plugins.push(
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                    filename: 'static/css/[name].css',
                    chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].chunk.css',
                    publicPath: '/subfolder/'
            })
        );
        return config
    },
};
module.exports = withSass(withCss(config));
```

I've tried this too, and it doesn't work either.

```
 config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "url-loader",
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192,
                            fallback: "file-loader",
                            publicPath: "/subfolder/",
                            outputPath: "/subfolder/",
                            name: "/subfolder/[name].[ext]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: You can also use postcss-cli with postcss-url plugins

Comment: Thank you very much, I have searched for information thanks to your answer and I have been able to solve it, I will publish the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @grzegorz-t comment I have been able to solve it, I put the solution here.

```
npm install postcss-url --save-dev
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const subFolder = isProd ? '/subfolder' : '';

module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-url': {
            url: (asset) => {
               if (asset.url[0] === '/'){
                   return subFolder+asset.url
               }
                return asset.url;
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
};
```

Comment: I make practically all changes to css only using postcss. Postcss is such a babel but for css;)